# Margin Convention bugs?

Tags: d3.js

At the following link Mike Bostock displays a "Margin Convention":

[Margin Convention](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3019563/)

(The full page describing the Margin Convention is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563).)

In Chrome (Version 53.0.2785.143 m) when I enter the developer window (by pressing F12) I get the following error messages in the console:

```
d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: <marker> attribute markerWidth: A negative value is not valid. ("-6")i @ d3.v3.min.js:1

http://bl.ocks.org/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

When I load the same page into Firefox  and press F12 I do not get any error messages. This might suggest that Chrome is flagging non-existent errors, but in my experience when Chrome flags an error there really is an error. However, I'm willing to have my faith in Chrome corrected by others.

I am currently playing around with the Margin Convention code and I'd like to begin with it in a bug-free state. Does anyone know why these messages are appearing in Chrome and how they can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really *is* an error as the spec has it for [`markerWidth`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerWidthAttribute):

> A negative value is an error (see Error processing).

That, however, applies only to the little marker triangles defined in the `defs` section. The rest of the code comes without further errors. To get rid of the error you just need to change the setting of `markerWidth` from `-6` to `+6`.

```
defs.append("marker")
    .attr("id", "triangle-start")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 10)
    .attr("refY", 5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)    // Turn -6 into +6 on this line
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");
```

---

As it turns out the above will eliminate the error but also flip the arrow at the lower border. Using `-6` for the `markerWidth` seems to be just a dirty hack to flip the arrow. The most easy way will be to get rid of the `triangle-start` altogether and use the marker for `triangle-end` instead. You only need to switch values for `y1` and `y2`on that line:

```
svg.append("line")
    .attr("class", "arrow")
    .attr("x1", innerWidth / 2)
    .attr("x2", innerWidth / 2)
    .attr("y2", innerHeight - padding.bottom)   // previous y1
    .attr("y1", innerHeight)                    // previous y2
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#triangle-end)");  // use marker-end like all other lines
//    .attr("y1", innerHeight - padding.bottom)
//    .attr("y2", innerHeight)
//    .attr("marker-start", "url(#triangle-start)");
```

Have a look at this working [example](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/3d2567751036500ea94be9ae68dbcccc).

Comment: @Argent I just realized that this is not enough as it will flip the arrow at the bottom. I am going to post an update soon. Stay tuned ;-)

Comment: When -6 is changed to 6, the triangle is flipped into the display area, pointing down, which is not the desired visual result. To get the desired visual result, which is the triangle outside the display area and pointing up, you need to set markerWidth to -6. This suggests that d3 may be generating a spurious error.

Comment: @Argent Have a look at the update, which shows the desired result.

Comment: The revised code does indeed orient the lower little triangle correctly with no error being flagged. Thanks!

Comment: @altocumulus consider sending a tweet to Mike Bostock warning him about this